# Post was placed on crawlspace vent cutout

Tags: framing, post, crawlspace

I'm a first time home buyer doing a new kitchen addition. The structural engineer drew out a framing plan where he put posts over a crawl space vent cutout. See photo for full detail. This is giving me a lot of anxiety and my GC for some reason has not flagged this either. This problem was not caught in plan check either. I'm  submitting amendments, so not sure if this was the case in the original plan or if my GC has built it according to original for inspection purposes and will fix it once the amendment is approved. Any advice on what I should do?

[image]
This:
[image]
and this:
[image]

Comment: The leftover joists plus the bottom plate plate remind me a lot of a double top plate, where double top plates accept roof rafter weights just fine. These "posts" are too nondescript. What loads do they carry? Is there a hip roof or something? Because I see joists running parallel with the notched joists, where that makes me think "nonbearing wall."

Comment: Are vents shown in the engineer's drawings? If so, you can be assured that the structure adequately supports the loads above, unless the engineer likes losing their license. If not, who put them there?

Comment: You need to communicate with your GC and then possibly the engineer.

Comment: Added another photo of the full vertical length of the post. The top is being built as a deck and needs to support active loads (including people). From what I can tell from the original plan and the amendment plan is that the vent spaces were moved in he drawings but they were already cut out by the GC as he was going by the original plan and not the amendment. Can he close and move the vent now or will a lot of things need to be torn down?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario, I imagine installing blocking to restore the load path. Rather than making something to fill the existing gap, you would probably cut away the remaining joist material above the notches and install new chunks of 2x10 or whatever that is.

Those joists above the foundation are technically part of the lateral system, but an interruption at such blocking isn't a big deal. I guess the floor sheathing fasteners won't get typical embedment in the underlying blocking with the bottom plate in the way, so the fastener schedule may be unorthodox.